# Optimization of a tabulation under constraint

Tags: matrices, optimization

Given a tabulation contening in each cell some text wich need some space to be readable, how to adjust the sizes of the rows and the columns in order to have the tabulation as small as possible? I have asked myself this question, and I haven't managed to solve it so far. I can reformulate it as follow:

> Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix of positive real numbers. Find $T$ a $m\times n$ matrix of positive real numbers such as:
>
> - $\text{rank}(T)=1$
> - $\forall (i,j)\in\{1,...,m\}\times\{1,...,n\}, T_{i,j}\geq A_{i,j}$
> - $\sum_{(i,j)\in\{1,...,m\}\times\{1,...,n\}}T_{i,j}$ is minimal.

For example, for $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$, the answer is $T=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2 \\
   2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$ : the sum if it's coefficients is 9, and it's impossible to have less than 9.

I guess it has been studied before, but I can't find any reference.

Comment: are you sure that you model the problem right? Are you that $T$ is only rank 1 and not $T= t e^T$ or $T= e t^T$?

Comment: $T$ is the matrix of the areas of the cells of the tabulation. A tabulation with rows of length $r_1,\dots,r_m$ and columns $c_1,\dots,c_n$ has an associate matrix $T=(r_i c_j)$. Conversely, if $\text{rank}(T)=1$, there exist $r_1,\dots,r_m$ and $c_1,\dots,c_n$ such as $T=(r_i c_j)$, i.e. $T$ represents a tabulation. I don''t see any other condition needed.

Comment: Are okay. I misunderstood tabulation. I thought you are looking for $r_i$'s or $c_j$'s separately. Rank conditions are usually difficult in optimizing. Have you try to express $T=rc^T$?

Comment: in your example why not $A=(2,1;2,4)$ or why not  $A=(1,1.0001;2,4)$?

Comment: for $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 1 \\
   2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$, $T=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2 \\
   2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$ is not satisfying the condition $T_{1,1}\geq A_{1,1}$, so it's not the solution anymore. For $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2 \\
   1.0001 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$, $T$ is still the solution.

Comment: For $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 1 \\
   2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$, the solution is $T=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 2\sqrt{2} \\
   2\sqrt{2} & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Don't you need integer solutions?

Comment: No, I'm looking for real solutions

Answer (score 2):

**That is just an idea. I am not sure if it is efficient or not.**

I consider the problem in vector form
$$ \min_{r,c}\quad\sum_{i,j} r_i c_j  \quad \text{s.t.} \quad r_i c_j \ge a_{i,j},\, r_i, c_j > 0$$
for given $a_{i,j} \ge 0$.

Unlike that matrix formulation, the vector formulation has multiple optimal solutions. If $(r,c)$ is feasible, than $(\alpha r, \alpha^{-1} s)$ is also feasible for $\alpha > 0$, and they have the same objective value. So we need to add some kind of normalization like $r_1 = 1$, which I drop in the following for sake of convenience.

I will turn the problem into a smooth nonlinear convex problem:
Notice that $r_ic_j \ge a_{i,j}$ holds if and only if $\log(r_i) + \log(c_j) \ge \log(a_{i,j})$. By replacing $\log(r_i)$ with $\rho_i$ and $\log(c_j)$ with $\gamma_j$, we obtain
$$ \min_{\rho,\gamma}\quad \sum_{i,j} \exp(\rho_i + \gamma_j) \quad\text{s.t.}\quad \rho_i + \gamma_j \ge \log(a_{i,j}). $$
Now, the feasible set is a convex polyhedron and the objective is convex. So you can apply one of many well known smooth constrained optimization methods.